# Mavericks Finder No Coverflow

Tags: macos, finder, sort

I just upgraded to Mavericks (late I know), and I'm not much liking the new Finder sorting system. I had it arranged by modified, for workflow reasons, but I liked the grid too, not the coverflow rows that happen now.

Is there a way to have the grid and 'arranged by modified'?

*EDIT*
By grid I mean the old icon layout, which now only happens with 'arrange by name.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot see why this cannot be done.

Select grid :-

[image]

then choose:

[image]

And you should get something like this:

[image]

I you want to get rid of the grouping right click in the finder window

[image]

and `show View Options`

[image]

Set arrange to: By name

Set Sort by to : Date Modified

What you get is this:

[image]

Comment: That's not what I mean by grid, that's the coverflow rows. Sort by name is the 'grid' layout it used to be.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong terminology. Please explain in your question exactly what you mean by 'grid' as my answer uses the grid layout and NOT the coverflow layout.

Comment: You want the icons to be scrolled downwards, not sideways - is that what you mean?

Comment: I have made an edit that should give you what you want...sort by date but without the grouping

Comment: @Paul Gilfedder - Thanks! Weird that I didn't manage that when I was playing around with it.